# Why was this duplicate flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792234/why-does-establishing-a-jdbc-connection-freeze-the-ui-thread) rather old question updated on the main page and decided to mark it as duplicate. We have numerous questions and answers dealing with the topic, and seemingly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/java-whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run) is the canonical question.

The only answer to the flagged question can be compressed to "You called the wrong method, see xxx". In fact, in the comments we see a lovely exchange of:
 - `connection.start()`?
 - thanks it works... post it as solution and I will accept it

Which hints that the entire problem was just this - not understanding the difference between `start` and `run`.

My flag, however, was declined.

Why?

Comment: Was the flag actually declined, or just disputed?

Comment: @resueman Declined.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. Did you flag it from the triage queue, or outside? (BTW: [boom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25358917#25358917))

Comment: @Deduplicator Outside - just noticed it on the main page and decided to have a look.

Comment: Not knowing Java and not having scrutinized the answers, I notice that the first of the linked questions **seemed** to deal with the issue of freezing when connecting to a DB while the other one explained the difference between running and starting a thread. Now, those might be about the same issue **but** is it really that easy to find (and realize that it's connected) the latter one when googling for help to the former? I'm not making any claims. Just stating that to the ignorant me, I wouldn't think of looking for difference between run and start if my DB connection froze...

Comment: @KonradViltersten That's exactly the reason duplicate questions are not *deleted* but rather pointed to a single place with a more comprehensive answer, while allowing multiple descriptions by duplicate questions. The definition of [duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) on SO is `Basically, questions are duplicates if they have the same answers.`. Symptoms and wording may be different, but as long as the answer is the same, they are duplicates.

Comment: @Ordous Oh, I get it. Now that you mention it, it makes sense. However, I can understand why people get confused by the name of the phenomenon. Maybe it'd create less confusion if it was called *alternative phrasing* or something like that. At any rate, I just learned SO better. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9233851)

3 Members felt it needed to stay open:

```
Review completed Aug 20 at 21:39:
Noctis Skytower reviewed this Aug 20 at 21:39: Leave Open
Hanlet Escaño reviewed this Aug 20 at 21:11: Leave Open
josilber reviewed this Aug 20 at 20:49: Leave Open
```

and that explains why your flag was declined.

If you really think it is a duplicate you might want to leave a clear comment why you feel that is true because those 3 users didn't agree with you.

<sup>I see that nasty SOCVR room took charge of it</sup>

Comment: I honestly can't fathom a reason for it, it would be like explaining why water is wet... Maybe it has to do with that Java is not in the main tags for those users, and it *does* take either knowledge of Java or reading through the answers to understand what's happening (question phrasing is very different indeed). Anyway, since it was Mjollnir'd, what's the usual way to proceed? Delete this question, accept the answer or just leave it hanging?

Comment: @Ordous Sorry for the part I played in the bad review of your duplicate flag. I was thrown off by the large differences between the two questions' wording (e.g. the `start` function plays a key role in the dupe target but is not mentioned in the text of the question you flagged). Glad to see it got cleared up by others.

Comment: "I see that nasty SOCVR room took charge of it" ;)